# How to display an image with custom size in python with tkinter and pillow

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So what I am trying to achieve is to make a class in python that displays a resizeable image with custom width and height. My code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class closeIcon:
  path = ""
  width = 0
  height = 0
  xpos = 0
  ypos = 0
  onclick = 0
  canv = ""

  def __init__(self, path, width, height, xpos, ypos, onclick, canv):
    self.path = path
    self.width = width
    self.height =  height
    self.xpos = xpos
    self.ypos = ypos
    self.onclick = onclick
    self.canv = canv
    self.img = Image.open(path).resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img_ = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
    self.label = tk.Label(canv, image=self.img_)
    self.label.pack()
```

now the problem is that transparency gets ignored whenever I try to display the image that I resized with pillow as a tkinter label, and every other attempt to display the image with tkinter and have it resized by pillow resulted in an error. Is there any way of simply displaying an image in python as it works in javascript with the following code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "path to your image";
img.width = 200;
img.height = 200;
```

Comment: Even though the image is transparent, the background of a `Label` widget is not transparent.

Comment: OMG thank youu. Do you know if you can make the background transparent?

Comment: In addition to acw1668's comment and your question ... No you can't make a widget transparent (at least not how you would need it), but you don't have to. Just tell the `Label` background to be the same color as it's master.

Comment: Is `canv` a Canvas widget? If yes, use `canv.create_image(...)` instead of a label.

Comment: canv is a canvas, but i need a label. acw1668 solved it for me but I dont know how to mark it as the answer